# how to do an array with ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a code of html like this.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let dataMakanan of hehe">
      {{ dataMakanan.makanan }}<br>
      {{ dataMakanan.deskripsi }}<br>
      <ion-icon name="remove"(click)="kurangPorsi()"></ion-icon> {{counter}} <ion-icon name="add" (click)="tambahPorsi()"></ion-icon>

    </li>
  </ul>
```

this code means that i want to show the hehe as much as it gets and i want to do an increment or decrement on each value. But when i do the increment or decrement it will affect to all data.

For example it shows 3 data on the screen and i want to increment it..
All of data was plus by one, but all i want is to increment spesific data that i click.

i use firebase and ionic

i just want to do it flexible, not for 1 user only..

Comment: I don't understand what you want but I think that you need to use index with ngFor. *ngFor="let dataMakanan of hehe; let i = index;"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have counter for each object in your `hehe` array.

html:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let dataMakanan of hehe; let i = index">
        {{ dataMakanan.makanan }}<br>
        {{ dataMakanan.deskripsi }}<br>
        <ion-icon name="remove" (click)="kurangPorsi(i)"></ion-icon> 
        <!-- instead of common counter, we use separate counter for each object -->
        {{dataMakanan.counter}} 
        <ion-icon name="add" (click)="tambahPorsi(i)"></ion-icon>
    </li>
</ul>
```

ts:

```
public hehe = [
    { makanan: 'name1', deskripsi: 'description1', counter: 0 },
    { makanan: 'name2', deskripsi: 'description2', counter: 0 },
]

kurangPorsi(index: number) {
    this.hehe[index].counter--;
}

tambahPorsi(index: number) {
    this.hehe[index].counter++;
}
```

Comment: it shows NaN can you help me with this error. i tried like what you suggest should i add counter on my firebase with same entity like that ? because i just want to make it flexible not for i user only

Comment: For adding counter for each user you will probably need to store `userId`, 'itemId' and `counter`, so you can store the counter of each item  for each user. I don't know much about firebase but u can probably create a new table with above 3 fields and do an inner join to get data of all items for particular user who has logged in.